# SAS Error: Subquery evaluated to more than one row

Tags: select, sas, subquery, syntax-error, proc-sql

I am getting the message "ERROR: Subquery evaluated to more than one row. I have posted the working code below. I would like to know how this error can be resolved. Thank you in advance.

```
data have;
input Subject Type :$12. Date &:anydtdte. Procedure :$12. Measurement;
format date yymmdd10.;
datalines;

500   Initial    15 AUG 2017      Invasive     20 
500   Initial    18 SEPT 2018     Surface      35 
500   Followup   12 SEPT 2018     Invasive     54 
428   Followup    2 JUL 2019      Outer        29 
765   Seventh     3 JUL 2018      Other        13 
500   Followup    6 NOV 2018      Surface      98 
428   Initial     23 FEB 2018     Outer        10 
765   Initial     20 AUG 2019     Other        19 
610   Third       21 AUG 2018     Invasive     66 
610   Initial     27 Mar 2018     Invasive     17 
999   Dummy       17 mar 2020     Some          1
999   Dummy       18 mar 2020     Some          2
999   Dummy       19 mar 2020     Some          3
;

proc sql;
create table want as
select *,
    (select max(measurement) 
     from have 
     where subject=a.subject and type=a.type and procedure=a.procedure 
     having date = max(date)) / min(measurement) as ratio
from have as a
group by subject, type, procedure
order by subject, date;
quit;
```

Comment: Which versions of DATE and MEASUREMENT are you tying to reference?

Comment: Is there supposed to be one ratio value per subject, or one value per subject/type/procedure ?  Suppose I am brickskull, can you show which specific values are supposed to in the ration calculations.  Data can always be sorted, is there a reason it is disordered in the example data.

Comment: What is the answer that you expect for the input you show?

Comment: That certainly is an impressive list of issues in a single SQL query.  I already spot 5 problems without even knowing what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I don't get that error when I run your code. I just get the note "NOTE: The query requires remerging summary statistics back with the original data." (SAS 9.4 on Windows)
As asked in the other comments: what do you want to achieve conceptually? From your code It seems you would like to compute the ratio between the _latest_ `measurement` and the minimum `measurement` observed by group, and add that information as a new column in your _original_ dataset...(?)

Comment: @mastropi Yes, that is what I am trying to calculate. This is an example of a much larger data set that I am working with, and I feel that I am getting this error because of that. Therefore, I would appreciate a better program that may prevent this error from occurring.

Comment: OK. I will assume that the grouping variables on which you want to calculate the latest and minimum measurements are `subject` and `type` (i.e. I am excluding `procedure` so that the result is more interesting in terms of variability of `measurement` within each group).

Comment: @mastropi Yes, that is correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you are getting the message "ERROR: Subquery evaluated to more than one row" when you run the query on the **full dataset you are working with in real life** is because you have the `max(date)` value repeated for *at least one combination of the grouping variables* (i.e. `subject` and `type` in our assumption as per above comments).

In fact, the condition you apply in the sub-query `having date = max(date)` will return as many rows as records having `date` equal to `max(date)` for each grouping variables combination.

My suggestion is that you make sure your input dataset has only ONE RECORD per `subject`, `type`, `date`.(*)

If you do so, your query will work fine (although you could replace `max(measurement)` with simply `measurement` in your sub-query since there will be only one record per group having `date = max(date)`).

So, the final query would be:

```
PROC SQL;
    create table want as
    select a.*,
        (select measurement as measurement_last_date
         from have
         where subject = a.subject and type = a.type 
         having date = max(date)) / min(a.measurement) as ratio
    from have as a
    group by subject, type
    order by subject, type, date;
QUIT;
```

If you run this code in your input dataset (where I have changed the value of `measurement` for record 12 from 2 to 0.2 to make the result more clarifying) you would get:

```
Obs    Subject    Type              Date    Procedure    Measurement     ratio
 1      428      Followup    2019-07-02    Outer            29.0        1.0000
 2      428      Initial     2018-02-23    Outer            10.0        1.0000
 3      500      Followup    2018-09-12    Invasive         54.0        1.8148
 4      500      Followup    2018-11-06    Surface          98.0        1.8148
 5      500      Initial     2017-08-15    Invasive         20.0        1.7500
 6      500      Initial     2018-09-18    Surface          35.0        1.7500
 7      610      Initial     2018-03-27    Invasive         17.0        1.0000
 8      610      Third       2018-08-21    Invasive         66.0        1.0000
 9      765      Initial     2019-08-20    Other            19.0        1.0000
10      765      Seventh     2018-07-03    Other            13.0        1.0000
11      999      Dummy       2020-03-17    Some              1.0       15.0000
12      999      Dummy       2020-03-18    Some              0.2       15.0000
13      999      Dummy       2020-03-19    Some              3.0       15.0000
```

(*) The actual condition for this query to work without errors is that there is one record per `subject`, `type`, *"max(date) over subject-type"*, although this condition (where uniqueness is guaranteed on the `max(date)` as opposed to on *every* `date` per group) is unlikely to occur in an actual business case.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply! How do I make the data set have only one record per subject, type and date without altering the data set?

Comment: Well, it's impossible to make your dataset have only one record per subject, type, date _without_ modifying the dataset... It's not logically possible.
You should analyze the business problem and find out the most sensible way to aggregate the info contained in the other columns to achieve that one record per subject, type, date. Assuming your most important info is `measurement`, one way is to apply an aggregate function to that column, like average or sum, while GROUPING BY `subject, type, date`. (On a side please feel free to accept my answer if you think it answers your question, thanks!)

Comment: As a new contributor I kindly point you out to the instructions of what to do if you think an answer you received is helpful for your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers
You are not obliged to do this, but it helps the community. Thank you! :)